# Scrolling is hiding the content of page

Tags: css, scroll, ionic3

I'm developing a `hybrid` application using `Ionic-3`. My page has a radio button and a checkbox and when I scroll the page, it is hiding content and for some time it does not show some radio buttons or checkboxes after scroll. If we click on the empty space of the radio button it will be displayed automatically.

I have enclosed some images for understand problem better.

> At scrolling time

[image]

> After scroll

[image]

> Real page(Before scroll)

[image]

> Html

```
 <ion-header class="custom_headerz">
    <button class="button button-icon button-clear custom_btnz" (click)="back()">
        <img src="assets/imgs/B_arrow.png" alt="" style="height: 20px;">
       </button>
    <div class="usrname">{{username}}</div>
    <button class="button button-icon button-clear custom_btnRz2">
      <img src="assets/imgs/user.png" alt="error" style="width : 100% ; height : 100%">
    </button>
    <button class="button button-icon button-clear custom_btnRz">
      <img src="assets/imgs/logout.png" alt="error" style="width : 30px ; height : 30px" (click)="logout()">
</button>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
<div class="media_query">
    <ion-card class="cardd">
        <div class="pw_head">Wybierz Pracownika:</div>
        <div class="srow main_row">
           <div class="scol_18 sub_card radiusL vertical_centr">  <img src="assets/imgs/user2.png" alt="error" class="user2"></div>
             <div class="scol sub_cardbg">
                 <div class="srow choose_name" greyclr>{{username}}</div>
                 <div class="srow">
                     <div class="scol_15"><img src="assets/imgs/cc.png" alt="error" class="cc"></div>
                     <div class="scol_85" greyclr>loczasdsdf: <span class="amtspan">{{questionnaire_count}}</span></div>
                 </div> 
             </div>
             <div class="scol_10 sub_cardbg radiusR vertical_centr"><img src="assets/imgs/F_arrow.png" alt="error" class="f_arrow"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="pw_head">Rodzaj treningu:</div>
         <div class="srow main_row" (click)="change_type()">
            <div class="scol_18 sub_card_emp radiusL vertical_centr">  <img src="assets/imgs/done.png" alt="error" class="user2_emp"></div>
              <div class="scolD sub_cardbg vertical_centrD" greyclr>{{task_definition_name}}</div>
              <div class="scol_10 sub_cardbg radiusR vertical_centr"><img src="assets/imgs/F_arrow.png" alt="error" class="f_arrow"></div>
          </div>
     </ion-card>

     <ion-card class="cardd">
        <div class="pw_head">Ankieta:</div>

    <div *ngFor="let x of q_form">
    <div class="srow padding_0 margin_t_10">
        <div class="scol_10 pw_que_title1">{{x.id_task_area_definition}}</div>
        <div class="scol_55 pw_que_title2 vertical_centrD">{{x.tdp_position_description}}</div>
        <div class="scol_35 vertical_centr">
            <ion-item class="pw_ion_check pw_que_title3 font_12">
                <ion-label> type to fill </ion-label>
                <ion-checkbox ></ion-checkbox>
            </ion-item>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div *ngFor="let y of x.tdp_position_inputs">
         <div class="pw_head pw_question">
             <span style="font-weight:500;color: black">{{y.id_tdpv}})</span> {{y.tdpv_label}}
         </div>
         <div class="sel_ans">Wybierz</div>

         <div *ngFor="let z of dataSplit(y.tdpv_input_value_options)">
         <ion-list radio-group *ngIf="y.tdpv_input_type == 'radio'" [(ngModel)]="y.id_tdp">
            <ion-item class="pw_ion_check" >
                <ion-label class="pw_lable">{{z}}</ion-label>
                <ion-radio item-left class="pw_r_margin"></ion-radio>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="y.tdpv_input_type == 'check'">
        <ion-item class="pw_ion_check" *ngFor="let z of dataSplit(y.tdpv_input_value_options)">
            <ion-label>{{z}}</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="ans1B1"></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-item>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="y.tdpv_input_type == 'price'">
            <input class="pw_input ht_50" type="number" placeholder="Price">
        </div>
        <hr class="pw_hr">
    </div>
    </div>

 <textarea rows="4" cols="50" class="pw_input" placeholder="text text"></textarea>

        <button ion-button class="pw_submit_btn">Wyslik</button>
    </ion-card>
     </div>
</ion-content>
```

> SCSS

```
page-training {
 .custom_headerz{
     height: 56px !important;
     background-color: transparent;
     color: #fff;
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 56px;
     font-size: 20px;
     background-color: #c91025;
}
 .custom_btnz{
     position: absolute;
     background-color: transparent;
     font-size: 25px;
     float: left;
     margin: 10px 0px;
     left: 0;
     color: white;
     bottom: 0;
     line-height: 30px;
     width: 50px;
     z-index: 5000000;
     padding: 0;
}
 .custom_btnRz{
     position: absolute;
     background-color: transparent;
     font-size: 25px;
     float: left;
     margin: 5px 0px;
     right: 0;
     color: white;
     bottom: 0;
     line-height: 30px;
     z-index: 5000;
     width: 50px;
     padding: 0;
     height: 40px;
}
 .custom_btnRz2{
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #fff;
     font-size: 25px;
     float: left;
     right: 0;
     color: white;
     bottom: 0;
     line-height: 30px;
     z-index: 5000;
     height: 35px;
     width: 35px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     padding: 1px;
     margin: 10px;
     margin-right: 50px;
}
 .amtspan,.choose_name,.pw_que_title1,.sel_ans{
     font-weight:500 
}
 .sub_cardbg{
     background-color:#EDEDED;
     padding:0 5px;
     font-size:13px 
}
 .sub_card{
     background-color:#393939 
}
 .sub_card_emp{
     background-color:#EDEDED 
}
 .radiusL{
     border-radius:10px 0 0 10px 
}
 .radiusR{
     border-radius:0 10px 10px 0 
}
 .user2,.user2_emp{
     width:35px;
     height:35px;
     margin:auto;
     border-radius:50%;
     background-color:#fff 
}
 .user2_emp{
     padding:7px 
}
 .f_arrow{
     height:20px;
     width:20px 
}
 .cc{
     height:22px;
     width:22px 
}
 .choose_name{
     padding-bottom:0;
     margin-top:5px 
}
 [greyclr]{
     color:grey 
}
 .amtspan{
     color:#c91025 
}
 .main_row{
     padding:0;
     margin:10px 0;
     min-height:58px 
}
 .scolD{
     -webkit-box-flex:1;
     -webkit-flex:1;
     -moz-box-flex:1;
     -moz-flex:1;
     -ms-flex:1;
     flex:1;
     padding:5px;
     width:100% 
}
 .vertical_centrD{
     display:-webkit-box;
     display:-ms-flexbox;
     display:-webkit-flex;
     display:flex;
     -webkit-box-pack:center;
     -ms-flex-pack:center;
     -webkit-justify-content:center;
     justify-content:left;
     -webkit-box-align:center;
     -ms-flex-align:center;
     -webkit-align-items:center;
     align-items:center 
}
 .pw_padd{
     padding:0 5px 
}
 .pw_que_title1{
     background-color:#393939;
     color:#fff;
     text-align:center;
     font-size:18px;
     height:35px;
     line-height:35px;
     border-radius:10px 0 0 10px 
}
 .pw_que_title2,.pw_que_title3{
     padding:0 10px;
     font-size:12px;
     color:#424242;
     height:35px;
     background-color:#ededed;
}
 .pw_que_title2S{
     line-height: 18px;
     padding: 0 10px;
     font-size: 13px;
     color: #424242;
     height: 35px;
     background-color: #ededed;
}
 .pw_que_title3{
     border-radius:0 10px 10px 0 
}
 .pw_question{
     color:grey;
     font-size:14px;
     line-height:20px 
}
 .sel_ans{
     padding:5px 
}
 .pw_radio{
     color:grey;
     font-size:13px;
     margin:10px 5px 
}
 .pw_r_margin{
     margin-right:5px 
}
 .pw_hr{
     margin:20px 0 
}
 .pw_star{
     color:#c91025;
     font-size:30px;
     text-align:right;
     padding:0;
     height:40px;
     line-height:40px 
}
 .rate_star{
     float:left;
     font-size:13px;
     color:grey;
     padding-left:10px 
}
 .pw_input{
     width:100%;
     margin:15px 0;
     border:none;
     background-color:#ededed;
     height:80px;
     border-radius:10px;
     padding:10px;
     font-size:13px;
     color:grey 
}
 .pw_submit_btn,.pw_submit_btn:active{
     display:table;
     margin:20px auto 30px;
     width:45%;
     height:45px;
     border-radius:8px;
     font-size:13px 
}
 .pw_submit_btn{
     background-color:#c91025 
}
 .pw_submit_btn:active{
     background-color:#e0122a 
}
 .pw_ion_check{
     padding:0;
     color:grey;
     font-size:14px;
     min-height:20px 
}
 .item-md .radio-md,.item.item-md .checkbox-md{
     margin:5px!important 
}
 .item-ios .radio-ios,.item.item-ios .checkbox-ios{
     margin:5px!important 
}
 .header-ios{
     padding-top: 10px;
     height: 66px !important;
}
 .cardd {
     padding: 5px 10px;
     border-radius: 10px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 transparent, 0 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
     box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 transparent, 0 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
     width: 95%;
     margin: auto;
     margin-top: 10px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 .font_12{
     line-height: 19px;
}
 .pw_lable{
     white-space: pre-line 
}
```

}

> TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AlertProvider } from '../../providers/alert/alert';

@IonicPage()

@Component({
  selector: 'page-training',
  templateUrl: 'training.html',
})

export class TrainingPage {


  options: any[];
  q_form: any;
  questionnaire_count: any;
  task_definition_name: any;
  username: any;
  myRating: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public modalCtrl: ModalController,public alert: AlertProvider) {
    this.myRating=1
    this.options=[]
  }


  ionViewDidLoad() {

    console.log('ionViewDidLoad TrainingPage');
    this.username=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("PWA_user_data")).username

    this.task_definition_name=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("PWA_taskdata")).task_definition_name

    this.questionnaire_count=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("PWA_activeuser")).questionnaire_count

    this.q_form=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("PWA_taskdata")).task_definition_positions

    console.log(this.q_form)

  }


  dataSplit(data) {

      this.options = data.split(";");
      return this.options;

  }


  rating(data){

    this.myRating=data

  }

  back(){

    this.navCtrl.pop();

  }

  logout(){

    this.alert.ConfirmAlert()
    .then((results) =>this.handlelogout(results));

  }

  handlelogout(results){

    if(results=='Logout'){
      localStorage.setItem('PWA_user_login','false');
      this.navCtrl.setRoot("LoginPage")   
    }else{
      this.alert.showAlert("Error","Something went wrong!")
    }

  }


  change_type(){

    let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create('ChangeTypePage');
    profileModal.present();

  }


}
```

Comment: you need to provide the relevant code...

Comment: thanks, now i have provided code.